# Is it impossible to install R 4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS because r-base-core requires a libc6 version >= 2.29?

Tags: r, linux

I am trying to install R 4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS but I keep getting errors of

```
> sudo apt install r-base-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libicu66 (>= 66.1-1~) but it is not installable
               Depends: libreadline8 (>= 6.0) but it is not installable
               Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

when trying to install. I have removed and deleted R 3.6.3 and have added

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/
```

in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. Note that the above requires `libc6 (>= 2.29)` yet from what I have seen, it is NOT AVAILABLE for 18.04. Does this mean I have to upgrade to 19.04, or 20.04 in order to run R 4.0?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, for this there should be a single source
`deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/` in /etc/apt/sources.list
Unfortunately, I added `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/` by mistake which I removed to install R 4.0
R is successfully installed now.

Comment: Indeed, my AWS instance came with multiple R sources and leaving the `bionic` one solved the issue for me

Answer (score 10):

The problem may to be with your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Please check whether you have disabled all other repositories for R in there, e.g. it should not contain lines like `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/`

Comment: I got it to work by changing the line in the sources.list to: `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/`. On my other machine running focal 20, it is written as `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/` so the modification was made manually and worked after reinstalling R

Comment: Thank you ! I was stuck because of this conflict between apt-repo in the /etc/apt/sources.list !

Answer (score 5):

Question: Is your system otherwise current to 18.04?  If so, the upgrade *should just work*.  I wrote a blog post (prior to the release) about testing R 4.0.0 on 18.04 along with a video:

- blog post http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2020/04/11#024_rocker_r_4_0_0_testing
- slides with links http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/r4_r400_binaries.pdf
- video showing the upgrade  https://youtu.be/aa9lZJ7ZzKM

Two more recent (related) posts at http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/code/r4/ as well.

In short, on a system that is otherwise well (i.e. no other packages forced or conflicts or what have you), one just adds the new repo (shown in slides and video), updates the `apt` index and upgrades.  I have done the same for my 19.10 Ubuntu system in another video.

Comment: De Novo: Please don't do that.  If you want to reach quality readers for questions related to R installation on Debian or Ubuntu -- and are not getting anything here --- post on the r-sig-debian list.  But please do not assume I can spend my time so freely that I am on demand or call.  Sadly I also have some real obligations.

Comment: No offense intended. It was a request, not a demand. I pinged you because I sometimes get direct requests in my own areas of expertise. When my real obligations allow, I can choose to respond to if I'd like.

Answer (score 2):

**For Ubuntu User**

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

Remove each line which is similar of the below given path

deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/

save it and exit from editor

Then try to install R 4.1.3 as per the given way from the below link

https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

I have 18.04 and want R 4.x

I had to edit the etc/apt/sources.list to

1. not have R 3.5 in the sources
2. instead of having '... focal-cran40/' to have '... bionic-cran40/'.

Then I used

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-base
```

and it all worked

Comment: what do you mean by not having 3.5 in the sources? running ubuntu 20.04 having same problem

Comment: @schlumpel - in the directory "./etc/apt" there is a file "sources.list".  You can edit it with a text editor.  There is a line of text to the effect of "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/", mine was at line 54.  My 18.04 problem was that it had "focal-cran40" instead of "bionic-cran40".  Now, I am using 18.04 which is known as "bionic beaver" (https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/).  I think that 20.04 is known as "focal fossa".  You might want to be sure to have the "focal-cran40" and not the "bionic" one.

Answer (score -1):

I just met the same problems while install R 4.0 on Ubuntu 20.04
here is my solutions.
first I just want install R instead of r-base-core and so on. it didn't work that install all the r-base-core and r-base-dev so on.
read the official document https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/#install-r
carefully.
if the problems still exist, try renew `/etc/apt/sources.list`
use the complete document or cope the backup ones

Comment: This answer is not specific enough nor useful. Add more detail not just a link that could be broken in some short period of time. This answer is no better than 'read the manual.'