# Cannot install R - Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, installation

We followed instructions here - https://rtask.thinkr.fr/installation-of-r-4-0-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-and-tips-for-spatial-packages/ - to uninstall R:

```
sudo apt-get purge r-base* r-recommended r-cran-*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update
```

...seems to have worked because when we run `R` in command line we get `-bash: /usr/bin/R: No such file or directory`. However, when we try to install R using:

```
apt install --no-install-recommends r-base
```

...version 3.6.3 is installed, not version 4.0 or 4.1. Here is our machine type.

[image]

What can we do to get R version 4.1.0 (preferred) installed on our machine? I am worried that, perhaps it is not possible as if it were, v4 would be the default rather than v3... might it be the case that 16.04 is too old for R v4?

**Edit:** followed the instructions in the comment below, but ran into the following issue:

[image]

[image]

Comment: According to https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ Xenial Xerus (16.04; LTS) is compatible with R v4.1 - perhaps try the instructions on that page

Comment: yes i believe so. sudo apt-mark showhold is empty as well, per - https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages - I hoped this may reveal where the issue is but it did not

Comment: can i simply install r-base-core and r-recommended?

Comment: I don't know - I can't say whether it will work or not - if it was me, I would give it a shot, but it may result in having to delete everything and starting everything from scratch

Comment: I dont mind reinstalling libraries

Comment: so i have managed to completely mess this up as now I can not install any versions of R...

Comment: Have you considered installing docker and then R through rocker/r-base?

Comment: no i have not considered this. I am not a devops expert or particularly strong with Docker. We just need R working on this linux server and I had simply hoped it would be easier to upgrade from 3.6 to 4.1...

Comment: Argh - sorry! That's frustrating! I'm booting up a xenial VM now to see if I can help troubleshoot the issue. When you delete/purge everything, don't forget about the gpg key in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc

Comment: at this point i'd be happy to delete/purge everything and reinstall R from scratch, but this `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` is blocking me from doing anything

Comment: you think I should also remove `trusted.pgp` and `trusted.gpg~` in addition to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc`

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install r-base-dev` ([Ref](https://silvae86.github.io/2019/04/02/fix-broken-package-r-language-install/))?

Comment: at this point this is a whole new question, so i feel like a separate question thread may be appropriate? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69218469/cannot-install-r-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

Comment: @jay.sf just ran this, still receiving `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-dev : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.1.1-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be installed` - it does seem like some of the other "unmet depepdencies" are no longer appearing, which I think is good. but still getting this error

Comment: this only started happening after running the 4 commands here - cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu - perhaps I can undo these commands?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65035038/6574038 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/61586021/6574038 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/16093367/6574038 and https://askubuntu.com/a/436491

Comment: thanks. I'm going to rest on this before I throw my laptop into a wall, and will take a look at these tomorrow. appreciate the help big time

Comment: I've run into the same issue ("Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.") with an ubuntu 16.04 VM - i'll try a bunch of stuff and post what I find

Comment: Thanks. I just feel like I'm just throwing mud at the wall right now, hoping something will stick

Comment: @Canovice I can't remember the exact steps I've taken, but I've overcome exactly the same issue while installing R>4 on a Raspi. So it should be possible, the information is spread across the internet though. Perhaps try searching for _linux_ instead of _ubuntu_. Good luck, and please share your solution once you found it.

Comment: I've gotten nowhere with the VM. Even trying to install other packages (e.g. 'curl') throws up dependency issues - something is broken somewhere - sorry I couldn't help with your problem

Comment: @jared_mamrot ive simply reverted to a backup of our server from before this mess up. I will try again updating to r v4 in the future